# GPO Update: Missing GP In sysvol

Tags: windows, group-policy

I'm having a bit of trouble. I'm created a group policy to create a short to the desktop with a url link. I've done this in the pass without any issues, but now, i'm getting an error that one of the gp is missing on our DC1 and DC 2.
I determined that this isn't a replication issue as i was able to create files on both dc1 and dc2 respectively and both files were able to show up.
I did a dcspofix on dc1 and immediately did a gpupdate but i'm still getting that same error.
Computer policy could not be updated successfully. The following errors were encountered:

*The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows attempted to read the file \poz.ashiwi.org\SysVol\poz.ashiwi.org\Policies{BE2D7DD5-53D3-464F-BCE9-C4C30E750568}\gpt.ini from a domain controller and was not successful. Group Policy settings may not be applied until this event is resolved. This issue may be transient and could be caused by one or more of the following:
a) Name Resolution/Network Connectivity to the current domain controller.
b) File Replication Service Latency (a file created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller).
c) The Distributed File System (DFS) client has been disabled.
User Policy could not be updated successfully. The following errors were encountered:*

I did a gpresult /s computername /user domain\user to determine whether my test computer is in the correct test OU for Testing GPO.

I would like to by pass the missing GP or removed it so its no longer an issue. Is there anyone that can steer me to the right direction.

I would appreciate it.

Thanks,

DS

Comment: Have you confirmed the file exists?

Comment: dfs? which OS are you running?

Answer (score 0):

> I determined that this isn't a replication issue as i was able to
> create files on both dc1 and dc2 respectively and both files were able
> to show up.

Is it in the NETLOGON / SYSVOL's folder ?

> I would like to by pass the missing GP or removed it so its no longer
> an issue. Is there anyone that can steer me to the right direction.

If a temporary error happened when you created the GPO, yes you can delete it and recreate it. It should be sync'ed between DC-1 and DC-2 automatically.

You could make sure replication is ok while at it;

```
Repadmin /Showrepl
```

and check your DFS's console to be sure the SYSVOL volume is synced correctly. (if in FRS please let it know)